# loading images from API in collectionview ios

Tags: ios, swift, image, api, collectionview

This is my API: http://swaminarayanwales.org.uk/DailyDarshan/ExportJsonV2.php?sMandir=Nairobi-Temple&Target=real&sm=sm

I AM trying to get images from API in collection view

```
import UIKit

    struct Images: Decodable {
         let images = [imageUrl]()
     }

     struct imageUrl: Decodable {
        let imageloc: String
      }

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!
var imageses = [Images]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageses.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let url = URL(string: "http://swaminarayanwales.org.uk/DailyDarshan/ExportJsonV2.php?sMandir=Nairobi-Temple&Target=real&sm=sm%20)")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do{
            let jsonData =  try JSONDecoder().decode([Images].self, from: data)
            if let imgUrl = URL(string: jsonData[indexPath.row].images[indexPath.row].imageloc){
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imgUrl){
                    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch{
            print("error while decoding")
        }
    }.resume()
    return cell
}

}
```

i don't have Xib for collection cell

```
 import UIKit

 class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
 }
```

when i try to get response from API it gives me proper op in log file so API has no problem

but i am not able to load image response in collection view

i made 2 structure and second structure is used in first as array because in API images is in array form

when i run project i get no output.....

this is the out put of API

```
{
"mandir": "Nairobi-Temple",
"ShortName": "Nairobi EASST",
"date": "09\/01\/2021",
"fdate": "09 Jan 21",
"ImageFolder": "DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021",
"images": [{
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/1.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/10.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/11.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/12.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/13.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/14.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/15.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/16.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/2.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/3.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/4.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/5.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/6.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/7.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/8.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}, {
    "imageloc": "http:\/\/swaminarayanwales.org.uk\/DailyDarshan\/DailyDarshanNairobi-EASST\/09-01-2021\/\/9.jpg",
    "imageDimension": "485:1024"
}]
}
```

MY structure is already mentioned at the top

Answer (score 2):

There are a few serious design mistakes in your code.

First of all, never load images synchronously in `cellForRow/Item`.
Another mistake is that the root object of the JSON is a dictionary so it's `Images.self`

But first things first.

Give the structs more meaningful names and decode the url string directly as URL

```
struct ImageData : Decodable {
    let images : [Location]
}
struct Location: Decodable {
    let imageloc: URL
}
```

To load the images asynchronously and not inside the collection view datasource methods use `DispatchGroup` to load the images one by one and notify when all images are available.

Declare the data source array as an array of `UIImage`

```
var images = [UIImage]()
```

and replace `callAPI()` with

```
func callAPI(){
    let url = URL(string: "http://swaminarayanwales.org.uk/DailyDarshan/ExportJsonV2.php?sMandir=Nairobi-Temple&Target=real&sm=sm")!
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, error in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        do {
            let imageData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ImageData.self, from: data!)
            let imageURLs = imageData.images.map(\.imageloc)
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            for imageURL in imageURLs {
                group.enter()
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL){ data, response, error in
                    defer{ group.leave() }
                    if let error = error { print(error); return }
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                        self.images.append(image)
                    }
                }.resume()
                
            }
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Now the collection view datasource methods are simply

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Don't forget to set the identifier of the collection view cell to `Cell` in Interface Builder.

Comment: i don't have XIB so i thinkl no need to register

Comment: let imageURLs = imageData.images.map(\.imageloc) getting error here 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'

Comment: My bad, I overlooked *don't*. And I tested the code successfully. What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: swift 4.2 ......... excode version is 10.1

Comment: I see, then you have to write `imageData.images.map{$0.imageloc}`. Note also the braces instead of the parentheses.

Comment: if i do so i get another error.                 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL){ data, response, error in.  {} here 'Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)''

Comment: Actually the nested URLSession's should also work in Swift 4.2

Comment: so what should i do next

Comment: Sorry I don't know. Swift 4.2 is pretty old. The code works fine in Swift 5

Comment: okay no worries can you provide me simple soltion as i did?

Comment: A solution like yours cannot work.

Comment: okay  dear /....

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code

1. When you are getting response from the API, you need to populate the array "imageData".
2. Then you need to reload the collectionView by calling reloadData() method.

Comment: i am not able to populate array "imageData"

Comment: let jsondata = try JSONDecoder().decode(imageData.self, from: data) can  Not use array like this in decoder because decoder uses decodable type data and array is not that type so how can i use that array

Comment: i updated my answer can you check now whats the problem

Comment: Please send the code snippet of "ImageData" class or structure, and the JSON response as well.